# Combining 2 Commands in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need some helps.

So I have 2 commands using VBA in Excel. The first one is removing rows when column G is online and the value in column Q is BBC. Here is the code

```
    Sub RemoveRows()
    Dim i As Integer, LastRow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value = "Competi" And ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "Q").Value = "BBC" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

the second command is to rename cell in column H. Here is the code

```
Sub sentiment()
For Each cell In Range("H" & lastrow & ":H" & clastrow)
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case "sport"
            cell.Value = "(sport)"
        Case "politics"
            cell.Value = "(politics)"
        Case "weather"
            cell.Value = "(weather)"
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

I wonder is there any ways to combine those commands? thank you in advance.

Comment: You call many sub from one command button. Even you can call second sub after finishing first sub. Just call second sub `Call sentiment` before the line `End Sub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call many sub in one command button. Even you can call other sub to inside sub. Just add `Call YourOtherSubName` before the line `End Sub`. See below example from your given code.

```
Sub RemoveRows()
    Dim i As Integer, LastRow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value = "Competi" And ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "Q").Value = "BBC" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i

 Call sentiment 'Call the other sub.

End Sub
```